# Smartly Tracking Words Written in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, word-count

### The problem

I'm working on a creative writing application in Rails 4 and users have requested a feature that keeps them accountable to writing X words every day/week/month. What are the best ways to handle the problem of tracking words added over time?

### My current solution

I store a limited history of total words for each user, allowing me to compare total words in all of their chapters today to the total words in all of their chapters yesterday, last week, or last month.

### Edge cases I'm not handling (and am not sure how to handle)

What if a user deletes a large portion of a chapter and rewrites it or deletes an entire chapter or story? I don't want to penalize them for throwing out what they've previously written.

### EDIT:

I've just modified [the Levenshtein algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to count all words added, removed, or substituted, to give writers credit towards their writing goals for all those activities. You can see the code here:

```
def words_changed_since(second)
  first = self.split
  second = second.split
  matrix = [(0..first.length).to_a]
  (1..second.length).each do |j|
    matrix << [j] + [0] * (first.length)
  end

  (1..second.length).each do |i|
    (1..first.length).each do |j|
      if first[j-1] == second[i-1]
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1]
      else
        matrix[i][j] = [
          matrix[i-1][j],
          matrix[i][j-1],
          matrix[i-1][j-1],
        ].min + 1
      end
    end
  end
  return matrix.last.last
end
```

That's monkey-patched onto the String class in an initializer so that I can call `new_chapter_content.words_changed_since old_chapter_content` and it will only give me a positive number. I'm open to feedback on that algorithm, but I'm pretty happy with it for now. My biggest problems are now:

1. **Should I just store this in my postgres db, or should I use another store like redis?**
2. **Would it be a Very Bad Idea to *not* expire daily words and even track more frequently than daily, like every hour that the user writes? This would allow me to give writers a very granular history of their writing and also help them keep track of when they're most productive.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very good solution but also a bit complex would be to use some extern software to compare the text "before and after" each update. Git would be a obvious choice, and you could then even have version history like github pages and wikis works now! However there is also a lot of other programs out there, with the only purpose of comparing texts and finding difference. Just search for "text comparison tool" on google.

**Edit (git integration tools):**

I Found these gems that can be used to call git commands from ruby:

- https://github.com/mojombo/grit
- https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git.
- See more here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/git_Tools

**Edit 2 (text comparison tools):**

Here is some resources i found, that could be useful to compare texts:

Ruby Gems

- https://github.com/threedaymonk/text
- http://diff-lcs.rubyforge.org/

Online APIs

- http://www.apidiff.com/en/compare/
- https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API

**Edit 3 (my answers to the last questions):**
Good solution with the Levensthtein algorithm! I will try to answer you last two question, but there is no right answer so this is just my opinion:

1. **Should I just store this in my postgres db, or should I use another store like redis?**

   This is not really a key/value situation, and even if you changed the implementation can't i not see any reason to use Redis. Maybe if you later one experience problems with performance but i think for now that redis would be a premature and properly unnecessary optimization.
2. **Would it be a Very Bad Idea to not expire daily words and even track more frequently than daily, like every hour that the user writes? This would allow me to give writers a very granular history of their writing and also help them keep track of when they're most productive.**

   No it's not a bad idea. Postgres and most SQL databases in general are optimized to query a LOT of rows. It's faster to query one table with a lot of rows then several table (eg. joins) with few rows.

   However this also depends on how you are gonna use this data. Will you just query for the last day or so, or would you need to use the whole history of a users changes pretty often? Fx for making statistics or so? If that's the case, should you properly consider optimizing by having a table with summarized data over longer periods. I do this my self in some simple accounting software i have made, for showing stats over income and outcome (by showing summaries of each week instead of each single transaction separately).

Comment: I have thought of that, as I use git for my own version control, but I'm worried about scale. First of all, I think I'd have to at least double all the text stored in the DB (which may reach billions of words before long), by also keeping it stored on a local or remote git repository. I'm on heroku right now, so that probably means a remote repository, which means there'd be a lot of text soaking up bandwidth.

Comment: I have added some links to other resoureces (fx two gems) that you could use :) Im sure you can find more by searching on google.

Comment: Thank you, but I have an algorithm that works quite well now and as far as I can tell, none of those gems do the specific text comparison that I need anyway. They'll tell me lines and characters inserted and deleted (sometimes substituted), but not words. I have the code to do the text comparison now. I just need a couple practical questions at the end of my post answered now.

Comment: I have added some answers for your questions :)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you helping work through this with me and continuing to improve your answer as I made progress independently.

Comment: Glad I could be of service. No worries about the bounty.

Comment: Same here! Hope it helped you out :). Think you can take some good suggestions from both me and @WattsInABox, and he is btw right, forget what i said, if you need a good counter storage then could Redis be a very good solution! However always remember not to optimize before you need it; "premature optimization is the root of all evil." Good luck with you project!

Answer (score 2):

### Our Solution

We do similar things on a large scale. If you're worried about scalability then keeping this code inside a Rails app going off of a basic postgres database is not your best choice.

If you're going to be adding a bunch of metrics like this and if you're going to be counting words and diffs in the words by user, you should consider starting up a stream processing or batch processing platform. These solutions are not trivial, but worth it if you're going to need scale.

Our solution uses twitter storm (http://storm-project.net) with the data counters in Mongo. In fact, their example is a word count application. Redis, as you've asked about isn't a bad choice, actually. I disagree with @jokklan because redis can implement counter storage with next-to-no effort.

We do select the data out of a SQL database, so to start, postgres isn't a bad choice, but that will probably be the first thing you rip out when you start to really scale this thing.

We also have forked storm deploy to help bring up storm servers more reliably. https://github.com/korrelate/storm-deploy

### Other Options

Obviously, though, there are a bunch of different platforms to choose.

1. You can use Hadoop MapReduce (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html)
2. Pig which we use for other stuff through Mortar Data (http://www.mortardata.com)
3. Amazon EMR which would allow you to do basic MapReduce or Pig jobs but this is more of an platform choice, not a framework and implementation choice
4. Run some background jobs to compile this information using Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or Resque (not really recommended given sidekiq's advancements) or Iron Worker which runs as a service (http://www.iron.io/worker)

   Here's a good article on some of the choices I've mentioned and probably some others (http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/in-stream-big-data-processing/).

### Recommendation

I can't honestly give you a good recommendation without more information about what sort of scale you're talking about. Given that, I might be able to help narrow down your choices a little better. How many users? Are you serious about giving all that granularity (that's fine if you are, just help determines scale)? Are there other things you'll want to do besides counting and diff'ing?

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful and I wish I could have split the bounty between both you and jokklan, as you both gave me some new information and perspectives. I've voted this answer up and I hope others do as well.

Comment: There is several of these projects i haven't heard about (twitter storm, or Hadoop MapReduce, etc.) but yes there is definitely a lot of options. Seems to me that @WattsInABox knows more about this topic then i do! But in the end it's all about finding what fits your needs. Check these projects out, and see what your project needs the most :)! 
I would recommend something simple like Sidekiq to start out with (you definitely need some kind of background worker!), and wait with complex solutions to you need them, but again i haven't tried these out before, and it's really all up to you :)!

Comment: I agree with @jokklan. The decision entirely depends on scale (current and future) and how many features you're planning on adding to this. If you want something that you plan to build extensively on top of, it may be worth making the jump to more complex tech early.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar method to what you have proposed but would be based on saves.  It would also make for a smaller table.  You could have a model associated with the text with say DailyText just user_id, day, expiry date and number of words.  Then you could have triggers on the table(s) that store your text that essentially do the following:

On save on a update or insert update daily_text set number_of_words += length(:new) - length(:old) where day = date.day and user_id = user.id

This would give you a little flexibility, you could set the length(:new) - length(:old) to not go below zero or even count remove words separately in a removed_words column.

Or you could have a method in whatever program you're using that stores the previous length and length afterwards and just updates this simple table after a save.  It would essentially work the same way as a database trigger.

The expiry date would then just give you the ability to clear the database of old data.

Or if you wanted a really small table you could make day the day of the year 1 .. 365 then have a task that runs at midnight to clear the next days data.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: I've edited my question as I've come to similar conclusions about incrementing word count per save and I now have a nice algorithm for doing that. I'm thinking about not having these records expire, but don't want to kill my db performance in the process. You can see the bolded questions at the end of my edit for more info - I'd love your thoughts. Thanks!